# How to solve GRAVE: Unable to process Jar entry

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jar

On every server startup I get the following error:

GRAVE: Unable to process Jar entry

`Mai 15, 2017 10:39:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
GRAVE: Unable to process Jar entry [fr/package/model/someClass.class] from Jar [jar:file:/C:/Folder-dev/work/eclipse/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/web/WEB-INF/lib/package-model-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/] for annotations
java.io.EOFException`

This was a well known error that was caused by some incompatibility issues between TOMCAT 7 & JDK <= 6.

In my case I'm working with this configurations:

- Server number:  8.0.9.0
- Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.0.9
- Architecture:   amd64
- JVM Version:    1.8.0_131-b11

Can anyone help me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to tomcat 8.5 and everything works fine.